# How to define field in C# with initial value determined in block of code

Tags: c#

Hey I have a class and I want to add static field to it. I would like to determine value of this field in the block of code, sth like this:

```
public class MyClass
    ...
    public static DateTime Date
    {
    int year = 2022;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 31;
    Date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish. As written, it's hard to determine what your goal is. `public static DateTime Date = new DateTime(2022, 1, 31);` would accomplish exactly what you wrote in your question, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: I know that I can do this but I want to put this code into block because I want to have more complicated fields and it's easier to define its value in vblock of code using another variables

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also use a static constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Answer (score -2):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you want to do, but if you want a static property with a hardcoded value, this is a way to do it:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static DateTime Date => new DateTime(2022, 1, 31);
}
```